# onClick() to change button border color rather changing button color

Tags: android, android-button

I am new to android, Working in an alarm app. For that in this app, I have 7 round shaped buttons each denotes the days of a week starting from Sunday to Saturday.

What I want to do is when the user clicked on it I want to change the border color of the clicked button and the button text appears on a textview  .

And then if the user selects the buttons(days) randomly but the textview text (selected day ) should be in an ordered way .

ex: the user first select Wednesday then Sunday the textview first show the Wednesday then Sunday here Sunday comes 1 st automatically and Wednesday next .(each day will have a specific position if the user select the days randomly, textview will show all the days in an arranged manner )

demo.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mbtn_Sun"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Sun"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#e20a1f" />
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `Checkbox` instead.

Here below an example that shows a simple implementation:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_custom_background" />
```

Where `checkbox_custom_background.xml` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_button" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_button"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: but I can't place the text inside the checkbox @crgarridos

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064472/how-to-validate-which-checkbox-is-checked-in-android @crgarridos

Answer (score 0):

first of all initialise your button.

```
mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Sun);
```

then do like this

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_button);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mbtn_Sun"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Sun"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#e20a1f" />
```

and then use a selector

button_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_button"/>
</selector>
```