# How to validate which checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am new to android ,Here I have 7 check boxes in my application and I have customized it as in the image .Each checkbox is represents a day of the week .

What I want to do is ,If a user clicked on a checkbox the text of the clicked checkbox should appear on the above  TextView (by default if there is any checkbox is not clicked Textview text should be as "Never").

Here the Textview text should be in a ordered way ,I mean If I select all the check boxes randomly but the TextView text should be in a ordered way like Sun,Mon,.....Sat.

I know how to validate a checkbox is checked or not ,but When it comes to the above situation I don't know how it should be .

Can anyone help me to get this .

```
  private TreeMap<Integer, String> mAlarmDays = new TreeMap<>();

 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.mSun:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Sun")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sun is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(0, "Sun");
                break;
            case R.id.mMon:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Mon")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(1);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(1, "Mon");
                break;
            case R.id.mTue:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Tue")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(2);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(2, "Tue");
                break;
            case R.id.mWed:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Wed")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(3);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(3, "Wed");
                break;
            case R.id.mThu:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Thu")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(4);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(4, "Thu");
                break;
            case R.id.mFri:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Fri")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(5);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(5, "Fri");
                break;
            case R.id.mSat:
                if (mRepeat.getText().toString().contains("Sat")) {
                    mAlarmDays.remove(6);
                } else
                    mAlarmDays.put(6, "Sat");
                break;
        }
        StringBuilder repeatDays = new StringBuilder();
        if (mAlarmDays.size() == 0) {
            repeatDays = new StringBuilder("Never");
        } else {
            for (String day:mAlarmDays.values()) {
                repeatDays.append(day).append(" ");
            }
        }
        mRepeat.setText(repeatDays.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Why checkboxes and not radiobuttons?

Comment: @mTak from the looks of it, you can select multiple days... :)

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] of the code for the views

Comment: @cricket_007 okay I have attached the code I have tried so far

Comment: You might want use a regular list or even an array rather than a TreeMap

Comment: better approach would be model driven by creating a model for each of the checkboxes with `title` and a property `isChecked` and set it on `setCheckChanged{  }`. This way you'll have a better encapsulation of the objects and makes the data handling easier rather than a `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create one checkbox listener for all checkboxes which will iterate over them and build string for textview

Something like this:

```
CheckBox sunday = ...;
CheckBox monday = ...;
//......
CheckBox saturday = ...;
TextView label = ...;

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener changeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        List<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
        if (sunday.isChecked()) {
            days.add("Sun");
        }
        if (monday.isChecked()) {
            days.add("Mon");
        }
        //....
        if (saturday.isChecked()) {
            days.add("Sat");
        }
        if (days.size() != 0) {
            label.setText(TextUtils.join(", ", days));
        } else {
            label.setText("Never");
        }
    }
};

sunday.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeListener);
monday.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeListener);
//......
saturday.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you have the text set... but you can do something like.

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    System.out.println("checkBox clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for every checkbox.

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
      if(checkBox.isChecked()){
          Log.i("Checkbox", "Checkbox selected.");
    }else{
         Log.i("Checkbox", "Checkbox Not selected.");
    }
```